# Xamarin. How to show dialog in a loop?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin. I have the following dialog fragment:

```
public class EnableGpsDialog : DialogFragment
{
    public static EnableGpsDialog newInstance()
    {
        EnableGpsDialog d = new EnableGpsDialog();
        return d;
    }

    override public Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        var title = "Please, enable GPS";
        builder.SetTitle(title);
        builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", EnableGpsAction);
        var dialog = builder.Create();
        dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
    }

    private void EnableGpsAction(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

It works well, but I need this dialog to be shown while gps is disabled.
How can I achieve this? 
My approach (it shows nothing):

```
private void EnableGps()
    {
        LocationManager locationManager = null;
        while (true)
        {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
            if (locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider))
            {
                return;//gps is enabled
            }
            else
            {
                //show dialog
                EnableGpsDialog gpsDialog = new EnableGpsDialog();
                var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                gpsDialog.Show(transaction, "Enable GPS dialog fragment");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a BroadcastReceiver that monitors changes in the location service instead of trying to *poll* the location manager.

Register a runtime receiver:

```
ApplicationContext.RegisterReceiver(
     new GPSEnabledReceiver(ApplicationContext, GPSEnabledHandler), 
     new IntentFilter(LocationManager.ProvidersChangedAction)
);
```

Handle the change of your fragment in the event:

```
public void GPSEnabledHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Log.Debug("SO", "GPS Enabled");
}
```

The BroadcastReceiver subclass:

```
public class GPSEnabledReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    readonly Context context;
    readonly EventHandler locationEvent;

    public GPSEnabledReceiver(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }

    public GPSEnabledReceiver() {}

    public GPSEnabledReceiver(Context context, EventHandler locationEvent)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.locationEvent = locationEvent;
    }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (context?.GetSystemService(LocationService) is LocationManager locationManager && locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider))
        {
            locationEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```